# Customize right click menu in PowerPoint

Tags: xml, vsto, powerpoint, contextmenu

I am trying to add a new command/label to the basic right click menu in PowerPoint (i.e., the menu that appears when you right click a blank area within a slide). I've downloaded the list of office control IDs but can't seem to determine which context menu (idMso) is for the basic right click functionality.

Does anyone know which idMso I should use for this? Again, I would like to access the basic right click menu that appears when clicking a blank part of the slide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `ContextMenuFrame`as the idMso

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<contextMenus>
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuFrame"> 
<button id="idCustomItem" label="My custom menu item" onAction="CustomHandler" /> 
</contextMenu></contextMenus></customUI>
```

Comment: Maybe it is the correct solution, but having a bit more details/examples would be welcomed ;-)

Comment: **From Review**: This answer was flagged as low quality. While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some information about how your code solves the problem at hand. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Comment: I didn’t think there was a need to provide an example. The answer was relevant to the question posed. Nonetheless, I’ve updated with a sample snippet.